# Improving the badges

Tags: feature-request, badges

I think we can all agree that there should be a relation between the badges to indicate their significance, one such relation is the `color` (gold > silver > bronze) that is already implemented.
It's only natural for the `shape` to also constitute an indication of each badge's significance.

However the current badge shapes (lozenge > circle > triangle) do not follow any logical pattern.

[image]

I think it would make a lot more sense to associate the significance of a badge to its complexity in terms of how many edges the shape has.
Which results in the following (lozenge > triangle > circle) instead:

[image]

Comment: Or you see the circle as the regular polygon with infinitely many edges, which imposes yet a different order. I think whatever order you come up with will only intuitive for half the audience.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft You're right that there are multiple ways to make it make sense, but the important point i'm trying to make is that either way would be better than no order at all which is what we currently have. In general, just because there are multiple ways to design 1 thing doesn't mean we shouldn't at least chose between the ones that make the most sense.

Comment: There are shapes? `:)` Once you've been around for a bit, none of this *really* matters. I'd imagine the circle is *intentionally* placed in the middle to deter the possibility of a "quick glance" and mixing up the hard edged shapes. With the circle dividing the edged shapes, it's pretty clear even if it's not intuitive to everyone.

Comment: If you look at our logo: from the outside in it would be circle-diamond-triangle. So that would _also_ be a 'logical' order. There really is no 'intuitive order' as far as I'm concerned.